# C++: Searching and writing to a file to replace a string

Tags: c++, file, io

So I've created a simple test application. It's purpose is to either read or write to a text file. It's looking for the string "Firmware: ". The idea is that a device will have a package transferred to it and stored, then activated. I want to store the name of that package (Ex: Update1) and when I need to, query that and get the package name back (Read from the file).

**Problem 1:** It doesn't seem to be writing to the file.
**Problem 2:** When I get it to write to the file, in the case in which the line "Firmware: pkgName" exists, how do I replace pkgName with the new package name?

This program runs and compiles, so feel free to throw it in an IDE or text editor, it just doesn't fully do what I want. I am using log.txt as my sample file to read from. I'm sure there's a more simple way to do this. I've been at this for some time and I've become stumped.

Thanks for the help!

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int writeFile(string filename, string pkgName);
int readFile(string filename);

int main(void) {
    string filename = "log.txt", userInput, pkgName;
    system("touch log.txt");

    while (true) {
        cout << "Write or Read?\n>>>";
        cin >> userInput;

        if (userInput == "Write") {
            cout << "What's your package name?\n>>>";
            cin >> pkgName;
            writeFile(filename, pkgName);
        } else if (userInput == "Read") {
            readFile(filename);
        } else {
            cout << "Invalid Input";
        }
    }
}

int writeFile(string filename, string pkgName) {
    bool found, exists = true;
    string line, word;
    fstream firmwareFile;
    int pos, size, num = 1;
    firmwareFile.open(filename.c_str(), ios::in | ios::out | ios::app);
    //firmwareFile << "This is a test.";
    if (firmwareFile.is_open()) {
        while (!found) {
            getline(firmwareFile, line);
            pos = line.find("Firmware: ");
            if (pos != string::npos) {
                //Found It
                found = true;
                exists = true;
                size = line.size();
                word = line.substr(10, ((size - pos) + 10));
                cout << word << " is the old package name" << endl;
                //TODO - Replace that with the new package name
                firmwareFile.close();
            } else if (firmwareFile.eof()) {
                //Doesn't Exist
                found = true;
                exists = false;
                cout << "No last firmware package available.\n";
            } else {
                //Still Looking
                found = false;
                cout << "Searching line #" << num <<  endl;
            }
            num++;
            if (!exists) {
                firmwareFile << endl << "Firmware: " << pkgName << endl;
                cout << "Wrote package name to file\n" << endl;
            }
            firmwareFile.close();
        }   
    } else {
        cout << "Unable to open file";
    }
}

int readFile(string filename) {
    bool found;
    string line, word;
    fstream firmwareFile;
    int pos, size, num = 1;
    firmwareFile.open(filename.c_str(), ios::in | ios::out | ios::app);
    if (firmwareFile.is_open()) {
        while (!found) {
            getline(firmwareFile, line);
            pos = line.find("Firmware: ");
            if (pos != string::npos) {
                found = true;
                size = line.size();
                word = line.substr(10, ((size - pos) + 10));
                cout << word << endl;
            } else if (firmwareFile.eof()) {
                found = true;
                cout << "No last firmware package available.\n";
                firmwareFile << endl << "Firmware: ";
            } else {
                cout << "Searching line #" << num << endl;
            }
            num++;
        }
        firmwareFile.close();
    } else {
        cout << "Unable to open file";
        firmwareFile.close();
    }
    firmwareFile.close();
}
```

Here is the contents of my log.txt file (Everything but the line containing "Firmware: " is trivial)

```
You
Think
It's
Here
But
It's
Not
So
That
Sucks
Doesn't
It
?
Firmware: Update1
I
Hope
You
Caught
It
!
```

Comment: You'll have to open the file in binary mode if you want to write in random locations. The other option is to read the file in say vector of strings, replace the string you want, write a new file, delete the old and finaly rename the new one to the old name. Right now you're opening the stream with `ios::app`, so all write operations will append to the end of the file.

Comment: The only problem that I am faced with is that I can not delete the old file as this will be in a config file and I will need to copy the entire file. Am I not able to "simply" (Nothing is simple, I know) delete the line and append it at the end, or replace only the packageName on the line?

Comment: No, you can't just erase data from the middle of the file, you can only replace it. And you wouldn't delete the config file, you'd basically copy it with some data changed.

Comment: So essentially to complete the second problem I am faced with I would:
    Read each line and copy it to log.tmp
    Skip the line containing "Firmware: " and replace it 
    mv log.tmp log.txt
?

Comment: It's an option. I answered with some code. The other option is, as said, to open the log file in binary mode and to rewrite stuff. But that'll be trickier. One problem is when the new data is longer than the previous one.

Comment: I see your other answer, thanks! The binary option seems above me right now especially since the pkgName has no defined length and is expected to vary each time.

Comment: Find Working Code in the link : [http://stackoverflow.com/a/12406355/559746][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12406355/559746

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simplify things if you write another file with only the relevant line changed:

```
std::ifstream cfg("log.txt");
std::ofstream tmp("log.tmp");
std::string line;
std::string pkgName;

while(std::getline(cfg, line)) {
    if (line.find("Firmware:") != std::string::npos) {
        line = "Firmware: " + pkgName; 
    }
    tmp << line << '\n';
}
```

Now, renaming and deleting files is platform specific. If you want a portable solution, I suggest you look into Boost Filesystem library.

Comment: I am using an embedded Linux system, so I will just use:
`mv log.tmp log.txt` and it will over write it. Thanks! This will do the entire process of copying the file with the change? Seems like I was over complicating some things!

Comment: Don't forget some error checking, especially checking if streams are opened and in `good()` state before writing.

Comment: I have everything working except one thing. The copying isn't going as planned. I have found the string in the file and I then copy the contents over but I need to know how to start at the beginning of the file instead of the next line after the instance of "Firmware: ". Is there a way to do this with fstream?

Comment: @Cr4cKeR I suggest you open a new question for this problem. Hard to answer if you don't show the code.

Comment: Actually I figured it out. Originally it just printed everything after the "Firmware: " string. This is because I needed to start at the beginning of the file. To do this, I used firmwareFile.seekg(0) to set the position to the beginning of the file. Thanks for everything! Is there a way I can mark this as solved?

Answer (score 2):

Well. First question, in your function write file you have a variable `found` which you test in a while condition `while (!found) { ... }`. The problem is that when you first test this variable, you have not set it to any value. So you have undefined behaviour right there. Looking at the rest of you code I think you should be using a do while loop `do { ... } while (!found);` not a while loop. Looks like you have the same problem in readFile as well.

Second question is bad news I'm afraid. You cannot replace a string in a file unless you are replacing with a string of exactly the same length. It's just a limitation of the way files are organized on disk. The only way you can achieve a replacement is to read the whole file into memory, do the replacement in memory and then write the whole file back to disk.

Answer (score 2):

@jrok answered your problem 2, but I suspect that your code does not write every time because found is not initialized, and is therefore undefined, so half the time (about) your while loop will not execute at all. You need to initialize both found and exists like: `bool found = false, exists = true;`

Comment: I've switched the loop and initialized the boolean and I am still getting this issue of non writing. I suspect that it may be because I have the ios::app flag and I read until eof. Is there a way around this? If the line I am searching for is not there, how do I append it on the end? I;ve moved the firmwareFile << "Firmware: " << pkgName; to several different spaces but it is unable to write. If I uncomment the firmwareFile << "This is a test" line - it writes that just fine.

Comment: Once `eof` returns true, the stream is in error state and subsequent write operations will fail. Yon need to clear the error flags with `ios::clear()`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to replace the contents of a file in place (no deleting and renaming another file to its name), then you will need to read in the entire file, make the necessary changes to the file in memory, and then write out the entire contents of the in-memory file to the on-disk file, overwriting it.

If you are allowed to delete your source file, it is much easier to do these transformations. You just need to read in your source file, open a temp file and write out to it, making whatever changes you need on the fly. When done processing the source file, you delete it, and rename the new file to the same name as the original source file.